# Prove that series of orthogonal set of orthogonal projections converges

Tags: functional-analysis, orthogonality

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $(P_n)$ be sequence of orthogonal projections such that $P_mP_n=0$ for $n\neq m$. Prove that $\forall x\in H$, $\sum_n P_n(x)$ convergent.

I tried to prove it is a Cauchy sequence but it seems not work. Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: do you mean $P_n-P_m$ converges in norm to 0 as m,n go to infinity ?

Comment: Sorry, i miss so part of the question. Fixed, thank you.

Comment: hint: $P_n \perp P_m$

Comment: I thought I can play some tricks on inner product and tried for several times, but still have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any finite sum of the mutually orthogonal projections $P_m$ is an orthogonal projection, which gives
$$
           \|P_1x +P_2x + \cdots + P_mx \|^2 \le \|x\|^2 \\
          \|P_1x\|^2+\|P_2x\|^2+\cdots+\|P_mx\|^2 \le \|x\|^2.
$$
This forces $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|P_nx\|^2 < \infty$. And $y_m=\sum_{n=1}^{m}P_nx$ is a Cauchy sequence because
\begin{align}
      \| y_{m+k}-y_{m} \|^2 & = \| \sum_{n=m+1}^{m+k}P_nx \|^2 \\
       & = \sum_{n=m+1}^{m+k}\|P_nx\|^2 \rightarrow0 \mbox{ as } m\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align}
This gives meaning to the unordered sum $y=\sum_n P_n x$ as a limit.

Answer (score 0):

First observation : $P_n(H) \perp P_m(H)$. 
Consider $x \in H$. Therefore we have $P_n(x) \perp P_m(x)$ for all $m \neq n$.
Consider an orthonormal Hilbert basis $B_n$ for $P_n(H)$. Thus we have $\bar{\bigoplus} _{i = 1} ^{infty} P_i(H)$ (the $cspan$ of $\cup_{i=1} ^ {\infty} B_i$ is a closed subspace of H since $P_n(H)$ is closed (why?). So we consider the orthogonal complement of this subspace say $T$. Thus we have $H=\bar{\bigoplus} _{i >= 1} P_i(H) \bar{\bigoplus} T$
Then $(\bigoplus_{i=1} ^{infty}P_i) H=\bar{\bigoplus} _{i >= 1} P_i(H)$. Conclusion follows